# Deploying a pre-built container image in Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, yaml, google-kubernetes-engine, docker-image

I have a docker image in my local machine which I have pushed to Google Cloud Containers.
Now I want to deploy this image in Google Kubernetes Engine.

I am following the steps in below link -

https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-gke#deploying_a_pre-built_container_image

I will create a YAML deployment config file.

My problem is where Do I need to keep this file in google cloud so that it can be used for deployment.
Also, in YAML file what is nginx - I have used the default one. Where do I need to keep this YAML config file.
ms_aggregator is name of my image

```
 apiVersion: "apps/v1"
kind: "Deployment"
metadata:
  name: "deployment-aggregator"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "nginx-1"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: "nginx-1"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: "nginx-1"
        image: "ms_aggregator"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the full image name, that usually includes the image registry and repository.

From the example:

```
"gcr.io/cloud-builders/gke-deploy"
```

Usually, the GCP format is

```
<docker registry host>/<gcp-project-name>/<image-name>
```

For you, this is likely:

```
gcr.io/<your-gcp-project-name>/ms_aggregator
```

But if you have choosed to use a registry in a different location, the registry name could be e.g. `eu.gcr.io`

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two things. The docs which you are referring is of GKE deploy builder which is a wrapper around kubectl. This will deploy the built image using Google Cloud's recommended  deployment mechanism and you do not need a Kubernetes deployment yaml file. This is more of CI/CD a style.

Now if you want to deploy the pre built image using a Kubernetes deployment yaml that you have already you do not need GKE deploy and you can configure and use kubectl directly for this.

Following this guide [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-access-for-kubectl) configure `kubectl` to access GKE cluster.

After that you can do `kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml` to deploy the image as a container in GKE. The `deployment.yaml` file can be anywhere in the system where you are configuring `kubectl`